# Parse JSON like dictionary from command line

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to parse a JSON like dictionary from command line 
I want to pass something like

--myflags {'foo':'bar', 'foo2':bar2'}

When I use

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
console.dir(argv)
```

It reads the output as

```
3: --myflags
4: {'
5: foo':
6: 'bar',
7: 'foo2':
8: 'bar2'
9: }
```

var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
console.dir(argv)

It reads the values as

```
 '{\'' }
```

How do i read the complete dicT?

Answer (score 1):

JSON uses double quotes and in the shell you have to enclose your string in quotes to treat it as a single word:

```
--myflags '{"foo": "bar", "foo2": "bar2"}'
```

If you don't care about it being valid JSON you can use single quotes and enclose it in double quotes in the shell:

```
--myflags "{'foo': 'baz', 'foo2', 'baz2'}"
```

For completeness, you can also escape double quotes inside double quotes.

Comment: It's not JSON, but it is JSON-like, which is what the OP said. Could you use double quotes on the outside if the properties used single quotes?